# Python Error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function'

Tags: python, jupyter

I am working on an assignment . I keep getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'function' even after researching the error and applying the suggested fixes. I'm not looking for anyone to hand me a solution, but I would appreciate a second look. I'm missing something but I don't know what. This is the section of code I'm having trouble with:

```
accuracies = [calculate_accuracy(df['Close'].iloc[-test_size:].values, r) for r in results]

plt.figure(figsize = (15, 5))
for no, r in enumerate(results):
    plt.plot(r, label = 'forecast %d'%(no + 1))
plt.plot(df['Close'].iloc[-test_size:].values, label = 'true trend', c = 'black')
plt.legend()
plt.title('average accuracy: %.4f'%(np.mean(accuracies)))
plt.show()
```

And the response code received is:

```
<ipython-input-109-bece89ad4cea> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 accuracies = [calculate_accuracy(df['Close'].iloc[-test_size:].values, r) for r in results]
      2 
      3 plt.figure(figsize = (15, 5))
      4 for no, r in enumerate(results):
      5     plt.plot(r, label = 'forecast %d'%(no + 1))

<ipython-input-105-f18f06dc1a5f> in calculate_accuracy(real, predict)
     60 def calculate_accuracy(real, predict):
     61     real = np.array(real) + 1
---> 62     predict = np.array(predict) + 1
     63     percentage = 1 - np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square((real - predict) / real)))
     64     return percentage * 100

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'
```

If you have any insight into this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I understand correctly (please provide a [mre]): you see, `df['Close'].iloc[-test_size:].values` is a function itself, and, to get the values, you'd have to call it: `accuracies = [calculate_accuracy(df['Close'].iloc[-test_size:].values(), r) for r in results]`

Comment: @Богдан Опир, normally for a dataframe `values` is correct, producing an array.  That's what I think the code is supposed to do.  `values()` is a `dict` method.  But a dict.values() object wouldn't work in `calculate_accuracy`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for clarifying, does that make all of the answers irrelevant in that caase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone's been focusing on the `values`.  But `values` is a valid usage for a `DataFrame`.  `values()` is dictionary usage.

Look more carefully at the traceback:

```
<ipython-input-109-bece89ad4cea> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 accuracies = [calculate_accuracy(df['Close'].iloc[-test_size:].values, r) for r in results]
...
<ipython-input-105-f18f06dc1a5f> in calculate_accuracy(real, predict)
     60 def calculate_accuracy(real, predict):
     61     real = np.array(real) + 1
---> 62     predict = np.array(predict) + 1
...

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'
```

The problem is with `predict`, the 2nd argument to `calculate_accuracy`, the element `r` from `results`.  The first argument `real` is ok.

That said, I can't imagine how `np.array(predict)` would produce a `function`.

What is `results`?  How's it produced?  The error suggests it's a list of functions.  Why?

You might also want to show the `calculate_accuracy` function, but we probably see enough of it in the error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

values is the function name, if you want to get the value of values, should call it by values().

Should replace

```py
calculate_accuracy(df['Close'].iloc[-test_size:].values
```

by

```py
calculate_accuracy(df['Close'].iloc[-test_size:].values()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @Богдан Опир, I don't buy that "answering for the future" reason.  Sometimes a question has lasting value, but I don't think this is one of those.  An answer that's useful for the current OP is useful for another poster with the SAME problem.

Comment: The problem here is much less specific than OP thought. So the answer itself should also be much less specific. If this question is "not one of those", it should either be edited so it is or closed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the part of the code that caused the error:

```
calculate_accuracy(df['Close'].iloc[-test_size:].values
```

At the end of the line, you see `.value`. 
`value` is a function that returns an array of all the values from
the specified dictionary, 
and just like any other function, you need `()` to call it, otherwise, you will only be referencing it.

If you `print(calculate_accuracy(df['Close'].iloc[-test_size:].values)`, 
you will get something like:

```
<built-in method values of dict object at 0x02AD2AF0>
```

---

Corrected code will be:

```
calculate_accuracy(df['Close'].iloc[-test_size:].values()
```

Comment: `values()` is not correct usage for a `pandas` dataframe.